# Generate widgets automatically for a generic layer's fields attributes in a custom feature form in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gui

I'm trying to create a custom attribute form in QGIS useful to modify the current layer. I have already created a custom interface in Qt-Designer with QLabels and QLineEdits. In particular, a generic QLineEdit is used to show the attribute of layer's feature and to achieve this I know that the objectName of a QLineEdit istance must have the same name as the field whose attribute I want to show. Like showed in the picture below. Until now no problem.

[image: Example of QLineEditr objectName in Qt Designer]

My goal is to create a custom attribute form usable with more than a specific layer so I need to generate automatically, from python code, the instances of QLineEdit class, each with specific objectName based on fields' name I want to show. I'm able to add custom widgets to the myDialog object, each named as the field I want to show, but QGIS seems not recognize the object and doesn't put the attributes inside the generic QLineEdit instance.

With these lines of code

```
...

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):

    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog
    global nameField

   main_layer = myDialog.layer()
   main_feature = myDialog.feature()

   # get useful widgets
   title_main_layer = myDialog.findChild(QLabel, "title_main_layer")
   title_target_layer = myDialog.findChild(QLabel,"title_target_layer")
   ok_button = dialog.findChild(QPushButton,"ok_button")   
   frame_main_layer = myDialog.findChild(QFrame, "frame_main_layer")
   # set the layout of this frame
   layout = QGridLayout(frame_main_layer)

   # get the list of layer's fields
   fields = [field.name() for field in main_layer.fields()]
   # add QLabels and QLineEdits inside frame
   for row, field_name in enumerate(fields):
       # label as illustrative scope
       label = QLabel(field_name)
       # lineedit to show the attribute of field
       lineedit = QLineEdit()
       lineedit.setObjectName(field_name)
       # add widgets to layout
       layout.addWidget(label,row,1)
       layout.addWidget(lineedit,row,2)

   ...
```

I get the widgets inside the frame highlighted in cyan, instead I want to get the bottom frame where each QLineEdit is filled with feature's attributes. Any suggestions?

[image: Current result and expected result]